# Is it possible to create different connections per client in SignalR? Persistent Connections

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am having more than one grid on UI and want to update through signalR . If there is some change then update the corresponding grid only , rest other grids will remain as it is . 
Is it possible to create different connections for different grids and update for each client accordingly. 
Also have to maintain the connection id's for different clients as well .
So , is there any possible way to sought out this scenario ??
Looking for some solution or suggestion .

ServerSide

```
public class RealTimeEndPoint : PersistentConnection
{
    //Create array to maiantain connections
    static List<string> connectedUserId = new List<string>();

    //Called when the first connection is made
    protected override Task OnConnected(IRequest request, string connectionId) 
    {
        return Connection.Broadcast("Connection " + connectionId + " connected");
    }

    //Called when connection is disconnected
    protected override Task OnDisconnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
    {
        connectedUserId.Remove(connectionId + ":" + request.User.Identity.Name);
        return Connection.Broadcast("Connection " + connectionId + " disconncted");
    }

    //Sends a value to specified signal
    protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
    {
        connectedUserId.Add(connectionId + ":" + request.User.Identity.Name);
        return Connection.Send(connectionId, "Connection " + connectionId + " sent " + data);
    }
}
```

ClientSide

```
myGrid1.on('rowcollapse', function (event) {
            GridConnection.stop();
        });

        myGrid1.on('rowexpand', function (event) {
            var row = event.args.rowindex;
            var value = myGrid1.jqxGrid('getcellvalue', row, "Name");                
            GridConnection.start().done(function () {
                GridConnection.send("P" + value);
            });
```

What i need is on expand start the connection and update data through signalR while after collapsing it should disconnect . The nymber of grids would be more than one . Hope this helps to clarrify my point .

Comment: I'm sure you can achieve what you want with only one connection. Would be easier to answer if you show some code

Comment: Thnxs @HallvarHelleseth for ur reply , updated raw code hope this would clarrify better

Comment: Why not use one connection and simply include the grid name or id as a property in the message that you sent to the client.  In the receive logic, you can conditionally decide which grid should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use my lib for this called

SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy

Install using nuget

```
Install-Package SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy
```

It takes care of the Hub and connection details for you under the hood, so that you only need to subscribe and publish events

Check wiki for how to set it up
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Once set up all you need todo to get it to listen to a back end event from javascript is

```
ViewModel = function() {
   signalR.eventAggregator.subscribe(MyApp.Events.TestEvent, this.onTestEvent, this);
};
```

You can listen to how many events you want on only one connection and one hub